# Unsupported connection setting "BATCH_JOINS"

Tags: ignite

How can I fix this problem, thanks!  The error message is below:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unsupported connection setting "BATCH_JOINS" [90113-190]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.readSettingsFromURL(ConnectionInfo.java:269)
at org.h2.engine.ConnectionInfo.<init>(ConnectionInfo.java:77)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:93)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:674)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:279)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$1.initialValue(IgniteH2Indexing.java:312)
```

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Can you share the code that is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

While the question certainly needs more details, it's very likely that you have a wrong H2 version set.
Try using H2 version 1.4.195.

See also this answer on the Ignite's user list: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Ignite-Version-2-0-startup-H2-error-td12532.html.

Comment: I had multiple h2 jars in my classpath, simply removed the one from older version and it worked.. cheers!!